# Why is this formatted string "n. def."?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, visual-studio, wpf, arcgis-api-wpf

I'd like to show the user the current map scale. I update the current map scale in a textblock  everytime the map size/scale has changed. This is my code, to show the map scale (in C#):

```
private void Map_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e){
    MapScaleTextBlock.Text = String.Format("Scale {0:N}", Map.Scale); //Note: It has to be formatted
}
```

and here is the xaml code:

```
<TextBlock Name="MapScaleTextBlock"></TextBlock>
```

The output is always this:

> Scale n. def.

Whats wrong? I searched already but I found nothing helpful.

I'm using ESRI API for WPF and C# in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have done it myself

It's not defined, because the method Map_SizeChanged(...) is not called in the initialization, it's called later. Got to put it somewhere else

EDIT:

Got to put it in here:

```
<esri:Map x:Name ="Map" ExtentChanged="Map_ExtentChanged" ... > ... </esri:Map>
```

and call it like this:

```
private void Map_ExtentChanged(object sender, ExtentEventArgs e){
    bool mustZoomToFullExtent = (e.NewExtent.Width > fullMapExtent.Width) || (e.NewExtent.Height > fullMapExtent.Height);
    if (mustZoomToFullExtent)
    {
        ZoomToFullExtent();
    }
}
```